# iPhone programmatically use wifi and Bluetooth at the same time?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, streaming, wifi

I'm interested If an iPhone/ iPad can use both wifi and Bluetooth at the same time for video streaming? I got a camera app that sends pictures through wifi, and am thinking if I can mirror this at the same time using Bluetooth. (Get a picture from wifi, resend it through Bluetooth) **Does wifi and Bluetooth  use different antennas**? Or is it one at a time or some form of sharing the same antenna?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wifi and Bluetooth use overlapping frequencies in the 2.4GHz ISM band.  In general this means they can conflict over the air.  Smartphones use a single combo chip that does both the Bluetooth and Wifi (and potentially FM radio and GPS).  These chips have "coexistence" logic that basically let each mode signal its activity to the other mode such that they can avoid clobbering each other.  For example, if a BT packet is being transmitted, a Wifi packet may be delayed to wait for the BT to complete.

This coexistence is handled automatically by the hardware, so an end user will likely not be able to tell the difference and it will appear that BT and Wifi can operate simultaneously.  But since they do block each other, there will be some decrease in maximum throughput if you were trying to max out a wifi and BT connection at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the info I've been looking for

Answer (score 1):

I tried streaming Netflix audio to a bluetooth speaker using iPhone 4 and iOS 7.1.2 without luck. The video would run a minute then stop while the busy signal went round and round, meaning the buffer was being filled up. The ratio of run-time to buffer-time was about even. Streaming just audio and web surfing is not much of a problem but clicks cam be heard occasionally. Streaming Netflix is not the same as streaming web content.
A wifi speaker and/or AirPlay is the only way without getting into DIY electronics projects.

Answer (score 0):

I have never programmed to use both but they should not be in conflict with one another.  I have been on the phone via bluetooth in my car while surfing the web using wifi so I'm thinking it should be fine.  Not while driving by the way, that would be dangerous.